# create a function to compute all pairwise cosine similarity of the row vectors in a 2-D matrix using only numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cosine-similarity

For example, given matrix

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

it should return

```
array([[1.        , 0.91465912, 0.87845859],
       [0.91465912, 1.        , 0.99663684],
       [0.87845859, 0.99663684, 1.        ]])
```

where the `(i, j)` entry of the result is the cosine similarity between the row vector `arr[i]` and the row vector `arr[j]`: `cos_sim[i, j] == CosSim(arr[i], arr[j])`.

As usual, the cosine similarity between two vectors  ,  is defined as:
[image]

This function should return a np.ndarray of shape (arr.shape[0], arr.shape[0])

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

1 - cdist(a, a, metric='cosine')
```

Output:

```
array([[1.        , 0.91465912, 0.87845859],
       [0.91465912, 1.        , 0.99663684],
       [0.87845859, 0.99663684, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But the requirement only allows using numpy~

Answer (score 2):

```
a

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Using the second formula, say
`pq`
[image]

```
p = a / np.linalg.norm(a, 2, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
p
array([[0.        , 0.18257419, 0.36514837, 0.54772256, 0.73029674],
       [0.31311215, 0.37573457, 0.438357  , 0.50097943, 0.56360186],
       [0.37011661, 0.40712827, 0.44413993, 0.48115159, 0.51816325]])
```

Note that the norm has to be calculated row wise. And so, we have above `axis=1`. Also, norms would be rank 1 vector. So, to convert into a shape `(3,1)` in this case, reshape would be required. Also, the above formula is for vector, when you apply to matrix, "the transpose part would be come second".

Now in this case, q is nothing but p iteslf. So, cosine similarity would be

```
np.dot(p, p.T)
array([[1.        , 0.91465912, 0.87845859],
       [0.91465912, 1.        , 0.99663684],
       [0.87845859, 0.99663684, 1.        ]])
```